# Is there a SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE equivalent in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

MySQL had a nifty command `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` that could write the result set into a file (CSV format or some other optional format).

I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio to query an MS-SQL backend server. I have multiple SQL queries and would like to write the output result set into a file. Is there any way I could store the results from a query directly into a file?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In SSMS, "Query" menu item... "Results to"... "Results to File"

Shortcut = CTRL+shift+F

You can set it globally too

"Tools"... "Options"... "Query Results"... "SQL Server".. "Default destination" drop down

Edit: after comment

In SSMS, "Query" menu item... "SQLCMD" mode

This allows you to run "command line" like actions.

A quick test in my SSMS 2008

```
:OUT c:\foo.txt
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
```

Edit, Sep 2012

```
:OUT c:\foo.txt
SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM sys.objects
```

Comment: Thank You. I am actually looking to do this through the query directly. Because I have multiple queries, the result of the previous query is stacked when I am executing batch queries.

Comment: +1 Genius! That works like a charm. Just a last request: Is it possible to specify the delimiter to be a comma as opposed to the plain formatting it does? Some of my values contain spaces in them, so the default formatting will make my parser very complex.

Comment: @Legend: "Tools"..blah.. "results to text".."Custom delimiter" options in SSMS. Only affects new query windows (edited this comment after trying it)

Comment: Nice...but how to drop the "XX rows affected" at the end? Doesn't seem to be an option in results to text.

Comment: @AndrewMao: add a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before the SELECT

Comment: (Typo in your edit, or you've come back in time from the far future to help people)

Comment: Thanks for that. But one thing that really bugs me that I can't interleave multiple `:OUT` statements with queries in the same script. If I run the whole thing, everything gets dumped to the same file. Is this some stupid thing where it parses the `:OUT` statements first (mushing them all together) and then runs the queries?

Comment: @AndrewMao You need to use `GO` for each file.

Comment: It seems like if your output exceeds a certain length it will only output to that length.  This is happening to me.

Comment: Good hints, since you have given shortcut to File mode, it is good to have shortcut to grid mode too which is CTRL+D and to Text mode is CTRL+T

Comment: For more detail, SQLCMD is described [elsewhere on SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097109/in-sql-server-management-studio-what-is-sqlcmd-mode).

Comment: BAD ANSWER.  Should warn user that SQL Server Management Studio is infamous for truncating columns at 256 characters; or at least in older versions it does.  Don't attempt to use this method unless you are sure that all text fields in your query are short.

Comment: @IAM_AL_X You can change that setting easily by just going to Query->Query Options->Results->Text and changing "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column"

Answer (score 11):

In SQL Management Studio you can:

1. Right click on the result set grid, select 'Save Result As...' and save in.
2. On a tool bar toggle 'Result to Text' button. This will prompt for file name on each query run.

If you need to automate it, use bcp tool.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the bcp tool. When I try it out, it gives me an error `Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'`. Would you mind giving me a short example on how to use it using SQL queries from a file?

Comment: Example: `bcp "SELECT Name, GroupName FROM HumanResources.Department" queryout c:\department.txt -c –T`

Comment: Do NOT use the SSMS method if you have any column longer than 256 characters.  It will silently truncate the column, or at least in older version of SS it does.

Comment: @IAM_AL_X You can change that setting easily by just going to Query->Query Options->Results->Text and changing "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column"