# SQL Server 2008 query output to CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I am using SQL Server 2008, I want to generate a CSV file using a select query. 
I am aware of SQL CMD and BCP but below are some of my constraints with it.

- There are a lot of parameters in my query and I have multiple queries that need to run sequentially/ and ability to rollback.
- I am running a query from within a Workflow product which doesn't provide an option to run a command See here([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ic5.png) )
- Don't have the luxury of visual studio or coding

I found an example for MySQL below, I'm looking one for a SQL Server 2008.

select * into outfile 'd:/report.csv' fields terminated by ',' from tableName;

Thanks in advance.
D

Comment: Does this former question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354130/is-there-a-select-into-outfile-equivalent-in-sql-server-management-studio I'm not sure what you mean by `I am running a query from within a WF product`

Comment: Can you use a batch file? Cause without running cmd commands or using management studio there aren't many more options.

Comment: @Used_By_Already That looks right to me - but maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry I used an abbreviation. I meant Workflow, I have a step within the workflow product to run queries.

Comment: @Doyizode try my answer it is working on my side

Comment: What is the workflow product? Or Tell us that workflow is capable of, so we know what to suggest.

Comment: The workflow product is called Laserfiche. It can run queries using a workflow activity but unfortunately there is no way to run a command. There is an activity to run script where you can write code but the whole point is to not use code and explore if CSV can be generated with just SELECT query (code is my last resort).Thanks again for taking interest guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps To Export Query Result to Comma Separated File**

- Open SQL Server Management Studio
- Connect to Server
- Then Go to Tools Menu  > Click on Options > Click on Query Results > 
  Click on SQL Server > Results To Text . See in Image Below -

[image]

- On Top there is Label Out format: and on top right corner you can see
  a combobox Select Comma delimited from combobox
- Then click ok
- This will output query result to .rpt file and This file has comma
  separated  data . You Can open this file with Microsoft Excel

**Recommendation :**

- After applying these steps close all already opened tabs and Then
  Open a new tab to test it works or not
- For Testing Write a query like 'select * from tablename' then Press
  F5 to run query
- This open opne a popup to save query result to file , give it a name 
  and it will be save with filename.rpt to desired location . You can
  open it with excel

Comment: Thank you Heemanshu, I have to run the query from a workflow product, not from SQL server management studio. Does that still work?

Comment: @Doyizode ok let me confirm that . Actually you specified that you will use sql server 2008 .

What type of workflow product you are using

Comment: @Doyizode have you tried answer available on link below -
http://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/77293/How-to-export-multivalue-token-into-csv-file

Comment: Will try and let you know.

Comment: @Doyizode ok go for it

Answer (score 0):

I found this query, it helped.

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SQL = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM table" queryout "c:\FILENAME.csv" -t, -c -T'

EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @SQL

Thanks again..