# BCP error "Unable to open BCP host data-file"

Tags: sql-server, cmd, bcp

I've just create a new table in my sqlserver name exporttable
 now I'm trying to push out using cmd bcp but om getting this following error:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Here is my path:

```
C:\Users\Serge>BCP Testing.bdo.Exporttable out "C:\Users\Serge\Desktop" -C -T
```

anyone can help ?

After trying Shnugos suggestion to add a filename I got this error:

> SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name
>   'Testing.bdo.ExportTable'. SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 11529 Error
>   = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error;
>   see previous errors for some of these. –

Comment: Have you tried googling that error message? Please show some research effort. People are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Answer (score 9):

From the error I take, that the data file cannot be opened:

```
C:\Users\Serge>BCP Testing.bdo.Exporttable out "C:\Users\Serge\Desktop\MyFile.txt" -C -T
```

I think, you have to add a filename behind the `\Desktop`. *Desktop* is an existing directory and cannot be opened as file ...

And - btw - it might be necessary to add `-S Servername`...

### UPDATE

Found this [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic237238-8-1.aspx)

> Whenever I get this message, it's because of one of three things:
>
> 1. The path/filename is incorrect (check your typing / spelling)
> 2. The file does not exist. (make sure the file is where you expect it
>    to be)
> 3. The file is already open by some other app. (close the other app to
>    release the file)
>
> For 1) and 2) - remember that paths are relative to where bcp is
> executing. Make sure that bcp.exe can access the file/path from it's
> context.

Comment: i've done that and i'm getting this errror

SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208

Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid 
object name 'Testing.bdo.ExportTable'.

SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 11529

Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.

Comment: Ok i Got it but i got one more question to ask you 
i manage to figure out but i'm getting this issue 
A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options.

Comment: @serge, I just see `Testing.bdo.Exporttable` in you command. Is this just a simple typo and you wanted to write `dbo`?

Comment: Really i'm sorry 
But i Still get the issue 
BCP Serge-st-11.Testing.dbo.ExportTable OUT "D:\Work\Sept.2016\"-C -T
i still get the same issue 
sorry I'm not so good with bcp.. i will be greatefull to get that sort it

Comment: @serge, Your path - again - has not got a file name... Use BCP with 3-part identifier and put the Server's name at the end using `-S ServerName`...

Comment: It was indeed the path for me, I was under the impression that bcp would create the missing folder for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you are running BCP through xp_cmdshell, run the following-->
xp_cmdshell 'whoami';
GO
--Make sure whatever user value you get back has full access to the file in question

Comment: This suggestion fixed my problem with the error `Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file`

Comment: I think, this would not work if you are accessing the SQL Server remotely (for example, Azure SQL Db etc.). Also see the post from @user5818738 above.

Answer (score 5):

Run: EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR C:\Users\Serge\Desktop', this will show if you have access to the path.

Remember if you are accessing SQL remotely or over a network, the output ie. "C:\Users\Serge\Desktop" will be the C drive on the SQL Server, not your remote PC you are working on.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have the schema spelled wrong.

C:\Users\Serge>BCP Testing.**bdo**.Exporttable out "C:\Users\Serge\Desktop" -C -T

s/b

C:\Users\Serge>BCP Testing.**dbo**.Exporttable out "C:\Users\Serge\Desktop" -C -T