# How to change JSON Column name in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I change the column name **"JSON_F52......"** to Any(e.g. SalesOrder)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i think the final result will not have anything with that name, it is a temporary name to store the result..

If you want the result in a variable 
The output of the `FOR JSON` clause is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, so you can assign it to any variable, as shown in the following example.

```
DECLARE @SalesOrder NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader FOR JSON AUTO)
```

Then `select from @SalesOrder`

If you want to store it in a file then check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354130/is-there-a-select-into-outfile-equivalent-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: While this works to remove the column name (`JSON_F52......`), your JSON results are left with an empty string as an index key `"": []` which is bad practice. Notably, this will break the dot-notation property accessor in JavaScript. The better solution, in my opinion, is to wrap the `SELECT` inside of another `SELECT` as described by `Michal D` below.

Answer (score 60):

Wrap your json building SELECT in another SELECT:

```
SELECT (
      SELECT SalesOrderNumber AS 'Order.Number',
             OrderDate AS 'Order.Date'
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
         FOR JSON PATH
) AS SalesOrder
```

Comment: Which of these answers do you think is faster?

Comment: This is the method I use. I arrived here looking for a possible alternative.

Comment: This method is faster than `Declare` Because no need use set data into variable. but change json type as object to string.

Comment: Yep this solution does the trick for me too, saves me having to write out a load of JSON logic in my code first (still supporting ASP code)

Comment: I would advise caution with this method, it can have a performance impact when fetching large results. "FOR JSON" usually splits long results into several rows of about ~2300 characters each, but I tried wrapping it like this today and it returned a single row of ~30 000 characters, seemingly causing a jump from ~600ms to ~6s